# How to create a 16 bytes Array for key to ShipHash in F#?

Tags: hash, f#

I am working on code where I need to hash values. SipHash seems like a great option.

```
  let getSipHashValue (buffer:byte []) (key:byte []) =
    match key.GetLength(0) with
    | 16  -> SipHash24.Hash64(buffer, key)
    | _   -> uint64(0)
```

Is there a way to pad the key to 16 bytes and make sure that it works?

I can get the exact length word as key but I would like to be able to use any word (that is shorter than 16 bytes) and just use some padding.

```
open System
open System.Text

let testKey : byte [] =
  Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes "accumulativeness"

Console.WriteLine("Length: {0}", testKey.GetLength(0))
```

Is there a way to do that in F#?

Comment: FYI you can use `key.Length` instead of `key.GetLength(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it:

```
open System
open System.Text

let rec getPaddedBytes (s:string) =
  let b = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes s
  match b.GetLength(0) with
  | 16 -> b
  | x when x < 16 -> getPaddedBytes (s + "0")
  | _ -> b[0..15]

Console.WriteLine("Length: {0}", testKey.GetLength(0))

let testBytes = getPaddedBytes "accum"
let testString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString testBytes

Console.WriteLine("X: {0}", testString)
```

I need to fix getting the first 16 bytes. Not sure about that syntax.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question what you want the padding to look like but you can pad with zeros with:

```
let getPadding (bs: byte[]): byte[] =
    let rem = bs.Length % 16
    let padBytes = if rem = 0 then 0 else (16 - rem)
    Array.zeroCreate padBytes

let pad (bs: byte[]): byte[] =
    Array.append bs (getPadding bs)
```

which you can then use with:

```
let padded = pad testKey
printfn "Key length: %d" padded.Length
```